# Regex that matches these form of floating point number +2.3, -.3, .6e+3, .6e-3, 2e-5

Tags: regex

I've created this Regex but it's not working when the input is 2e-5
[-+]?[0-9]*.[0-9]+(e[-+]?[0-9]+)?

Can I use condition in it like if a dot exists then exponent can be both positive or negative, else exponent must only be negative?

Comment: What programming language are you using? Why not just try parsing the input to a float?

Comment: @Mureinik I'm not making any program. I'm learning compiler and there is this question that asked me to write a Regex that accepts floating point number with specified form(I gave examples in my question) before drawing the regex's DFA, NFA 
Now I'm stuck at writing the regex.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/iZdqBZ/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you. But that Regex seems to accept 2e5 too.  I think 2e5 = 200000 and it should not be matched(?)

Comment: No idea, but perhaps, you need https://regex101.com/r/iZdqBZ/2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It works now. Thankyou!